# core data giving merge conflict with single MOC and main thread used for core data

Tags: core-data, merge, conflict, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I'm using core data with a single NSManagedObjectContext and am doing all operation for core data on the main thread. The new and old row given in error description are identical and am at hoping that someone can explain why am getting a merge conflict. Setting merge policy to overwrite is causing the app to run into high CPU in simulator and become unresponsive.

However, when I try to update managed objects in one entity, the app crashes with following error,

```
NSMergeConflict (0x7144390) for NSManagedObject (0x7225db0) with objectID '0x721c0a0 <x-coredata://94349DC2-C441-4102-9C65-60737E940135/Locations/p1>' with oldVersion = 2 and newVersion = 3 and 
old cached row = {\n    AccountInfo = \"0x721bae0 <x-coredata://94349DC2-C441-4102-9C65-60737E940135/Account/p1>\";\n    City = \"<null>\";\n    Country = \"Russian Federation\";\n    EntryStatusId = \"<null>\";\n    ExitStatusId = \"<null>\";\n    IsCorporateLocation = 1;\n    IsVisible = 1;\n    Latitude = 50;\n    LocationId = 10003;\n    Longitude = 40;\n    Name = \"Test Location\";\n    Radius = 304;\n    State = \"Province of Voronezh\";\n    Street = \"<null>\";\n    Units = METER;\n    Zip = \"<null>\";\n} and 
new database row = {\n    AccountInfo = \"0x7144560 <x-coredata://94349DC2-C441-4102-9C65-60737E940135/Account/p1>\";\n    City = \"<null>\";\n    Country = \"Russian Federation\";\n    EntryStatusId = \"<null>\";\n    ExitStatusId = \"<null>\";\n    IsCorporateLocation = 1;\n    IsVisible = 1;\n    Latitude = 50;\n    LocationId = 10003;\n    Longitude = 40;\n    Name = \"Test Location\";\n    Radius = 304;\n    State = \"Province of Voronezh\";\n    Street = \"<null>\";\n    Units = METER;\n    Zip = \"<null>\";\n}
```

Update: The error doesn't happen if I save the MOC after updating every object but happens if I update all the objects and then save MOC. Anyone knows why this is happening?

Comment: Thanks for the update! I was facing the same problem and this solved it. I'm now updating the objects using `refreshObject` AFTER saving the context and no more conflicts are showing up.

Answer (score 0):

The error suggest that you do actually have two separate contexts. You only get a merge when you have two or more context writing to the same store.

I would suggest logging the context before every save, everywhere you perform a save to make certain you only have one active context.

Comment: That was the first thing I tried (even though I access MOC via a singleton) and don't see a different MOC being logged. In fact, I did a cleanup of objects and then ran the same code twice. The first time when it inserted the objects everything went fine but second time when update happened, the app crashed with the same error.

Answer (score -1):

It is posible to let the Core Data deals with this conflicts automatically instead of throw an Exception. See this post: http://pauloliveira.net/tech/core-data-merging-conflicts

Comment: Per the FAQ, you need to disclose that the link provided goes to your site.  Also, please summarize the contents of the link instead of just supplying the link.